# issues with Find File in xemacs

Tags: cygwin, xemacs

Xemacs (V 21.4.22) is my primary editor on my Windows 10/cygwin machine. Everything worked find for WXP, W7, ... up to W10. Now when I use File/Open, the Find File window started by xemacs occupies my full screen. There is no icon on the Find File window that toggles between full screen and non-full screen. The Find File window looks very similar to Windows Explorer. This behavior is very inconvenient when I can't see other open windows as a reminder of the file name I want to open in xemacs. Any help would be appreciated.

A friend solved this problem in a few minutes. When the xemacs Find File window is opened full screen, double left click on the border and that acts as a toggle between full screen and non-full screen modes.

Comment: Please also post, which window manager you configured for Cygwin/X.